# Заполнение и замена данных в датафреймах

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Как заполнить фреймы типом данных NaN?

Comment: вы про  numpy.nan?

Comment: Вас устоит ответ - просто берёте и заменяете? ;) Если хотите более детальный ответ то приведите воспроизводимый пример данных и результат, который вы хотите получить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь одним из следующих методов:

- `DataFrame.replace`
- `DataFrame.where`
- `DataFrame.loc[...]`

Из вашего вопроса непонятно хотите ли вы заполнить весь фрейм `NaN’s` или какую-то его часть (по условиям или нет) и поэтому на вопрос такого качества невозможно дать конкретный ответ.

Для того чтобы получить более развёрнутый  ответ с примером кода приведите в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример данных и результат, который вы хотите получить.